# Margin on jobs advertisement in blogs

Tags: bug, design, blog

There's a link to an ad for Stack Overflow Jobs between content inside blog items, other images like this have a `<figure class="wp-block-image">` element to provide margin to top and bottom. The job advertisement seems to be a simple link tag (`<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/jobs"> -image- </a>`) which lacks the margin top.

[Link to article.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/22/how-stack-overflow-upgraded-from-windows-server-2012/?cb=1)

Image of the issue:
[image: description of the bug]

It's nitpicking, and perhaps a bit over the top to report this but hey, [it's honest work.](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/but-its-honest-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be fixed as of the 25th of July, but don't ask me how:

[image: Horrible BR fix with perfect red circle]